Module Augmentation: Modify existing property declaration
I'm customising a Material UI theme and attempting to reduce the number of `greys available for a theme
I've add my types to the Color type.
declare module "@mui/material" {
  interface Color {
    10: string; // new type works as expected
    20: string; // new type works as expected
    60: string; // new type works as expected
    100: string; // existing type no change works as expected

    200: unknown; // Existing type not updated to my declaration
  }
}

Then I've modified the theme:
const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    grey: {
      10: "#FAFBFE",
      20: "#EEF1F8",
      60: "#BABCBE",
      100: "#848A90",

      200: "#E5E8EC",
      // I'd expect this to give me a type error
      // But it has the original type (string | undefined) rather than the one I've declared.
    },
  },
});

Evidently, my understanding of how module augmentation works is incorrect.
Could you enlighten me as to why this doesn't work as I expect?

I'm not getting an error on the 200 line type no.

• Why would you expect a type error again? string is assignable to unknown. Are you using unknown on purpose? • This is the merging error I'm talking about. TS should (and does, in my example) complain about your inappropriate merging. If you don't see that error, then right now you don't have a [mre]. Maybe you have some interesting/relevant compiler options preventing that from being type checked? Please try to produce a [mre] so we can all agree on the symptoms of your problem.
